# Are these strawberries drying up?

Tags: vegetables, strawberries

Do these pictures of the strawberries look okay or are they drying up?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks pretty healthy?  What is your concern and why?

Comment: They look as though they've had insufficient water to me.

Comment: Graham is right, when the berries are growing they need more water to develop a nice psuedo-carp for you to eat. It doesn't affect the plan or its health, and the seeds will be just fine. The plant is ok, but you want to be sure they get plenty of water if you want to eat them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are perfectly okay!  The berries get heavy and droop, those leaves are perky and lush.  Make sure you pluck off rotting berries as soon as you are able, carefully and dispose away from your garden...or pots.  Don't overwater!  Water deeply and then allow to dry out. If these are in a greenhouse get some major ventilation going.